# PHP Storm Interpreter is not specified or invalid

Tags: phpstorm

I got this error as mentioned below. I don't understand how to set one as there's no interpreter to choose.

[image]

I will appreciate any help,
Eve

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually have PHP installed?

Because, if you do, it's as simple as clicking that button with the dots to the roight of where it says `<no interpreter>` and navigating to your PHP.EXE

Comment: there's no CLI interpreter to choose. how do i navigate to my PHP.EXE?

Comment: 1) Well, "there's no CLI interpreter to choose" sounds like you don't have PHP installed - do you? 2) "how do i navigate to my PHP.EXE?" - if you do have it installed, I already told you -> it's as simple as clicking that button with the dots to the roight of where it says <no interpreter> and navigating to your PHP.EXE